# Changing SQL Server database maximum size in Visual Studio for uploading in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure

I built a small `ASP.NET MVC web application` in Visual Studio 2015 and I want to upload it to Microsoft Azure with my `Microsoft Imagine Student` subscription. When I try to publish it, I get this error:

> Failed: /subscriptions/1(...)4/resourceGroups/Default-ApplicationInsights-EastUS/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sapromaniadbser/databases/Sap20170102030950_db ()
>   40619: The edition 'Free' does not support the database max size '1073741824'.

It's clear that I need to change my database max size, but how can I do this?

I created my project on `Visual Studio Team Services`, after I created the project on my local machine and I linked it with the project from `Visual Studio Team Services` for having version control. I wrote in `Package Manager Console` "enable-migrations", and I had my database. All resources are in the same resource group.

Comment: Where *did* you define it? How? Did you try to create your database in the same resource group as Application Insights?

Comment: Thanks in advance @PanagiotisKanavos . All the resources are in the same resource group. In Azure, I defined my database when I press publish in Visual Studio for publishing it to Azure. I create a new Application Plan with a new Database. The local DB was created when I wrote "enable-migrations" in `Package Manager Console`.

Answer (score 0):

The sql server in visual studio has a maximum of 5 Gb of space for you to use it..if you need more space download sql server and link the database to visual studio
The maximum space cannot be changed if you use the sql server integrated in visual studio

Comment: That's not what the OP asks. You are confusing LocalDB with Azure SQL

Answer (score 0):

You need buy it over 
https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/pricing/purchase-options/
i think.

Comment: That's 1GB of data. The problem is the configured maximum size, *NOT* the actual database size. Also note that this is an Application Insights URL, not a user database