# Publish webapp to Azure as student

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

Alright, so I have a Microsoft Imagine account from school through which I've gotten both Azure and Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 in order to learn ASP.NET (worked with Django earlier).

So I've gone throught a whole bunch of tutorials from codeschool to virtual academy to docs.microsoft and finally got the first version of my webapp done and ready to be published to Azure.

So I look through the steps on how to publish, here's some info on that:

- Subscription: Microsoft Imagine
- Resource Group: `<name>` (northeurope)
- App Service Plan:

  - Resource Group: `<name>`
  - Pricing Tier: Free
  - Location: North Europe
  - Status: Ready
  - Subscription Name: Microsoft Imagine

Click on "Explore additional azure services" (as per many tutorial instructions) and add a database, I've fortunately already created the database in Azure so I only have to connect it. Here's some info on the database (though creating it directly here generates the same error):

- Resource Group: `<name>`
- Status: Online
- Location: North Europe
- Subscription Name: Microsoft Imagine
- Server Name: `<servername>`.database.windows.net
- Pricing Tier: Free (5 DTUs)

Some info on the server that the server:

- Resource Group: `<name>`
- Status: Available
- Location: North Europe
- Status: Available

So everything looks really good and I'm ready to publish and I hit the `Create`-button.
Deploying: (step 0 out of 5) ...
Deploying: (step 4 out of 5) ...
**ERROR**

Details:

```
Template deployment failed. Deployment operation statuses:  

Succeeded: /subscriptions/ ... /servers/mintentadbserver ()

Failed: /subscriptions/ ... /databases/Mintenta_db ()
    40619: The edition 'Free' does not support the database data max size '1073741824'.

Succeeded: /subscriptions/ ... /firewallrules/AllowAllAzureIPs ()

Succeeded: /subscriptions/ ... /sites/MinTenta ()

Succeeded: /subscriptions/ ... /config/connectionstrings ()
```

The few duplicate questions I've found on this have close to no answers and just a few suggestions to upgrade ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428146/changing-sql-server-database-maximum-size-in-visual-studio-for-uploading-in-azur), [link2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2c45de40-91f5-4af7-a640-0971f0d25ca1/aspnet-core-web-app-the-edition-free-does-not-support-the-database-max-size-1073741824?forum=ssdsgetstarted)).

So I suppose my question is, like many others:
1) How do you change the size of the database?
2) If that's not possible and you cannot have a database with your free account. Why would not just say that instead of using size-restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is a little bit old, but I've just ran across the same error and I also couldn't find an answer. However, I managed to work around this issue.

I was following this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase) from Microsoft, and since you mentioned the same steps and the same message error I got, I'm assuming you were doing the same thing or at least something similar.

When publishing directly from Visual Studio 2017 to Azure, VS tries to create the following resources:

- App service plan
- App service
- SQL server
- SQL database

From your error message (and mine as well), although the SQL database creation had an error, the other resources were published successfully. So, if you access Azure portal, you'll see those resources there.

Then, if you open the SQL server and click "New database", you'll be able to add a database manually - and more importantly, you'll be able to select the free option with max size of 32MB.

[image: Azure portal example]

*(In this example, the button is disabled because I've already added one database - I believe this is another limitation from the students' subscription).*

Note that if you add the database manually, you'll also need to configure your connection strings. But that is quite easy:

- Open your new database on Azure portal
- Go to Settings > Connection Strings
- Copy the connection string from there
- Now open your App service and go to Settings > Application Settings
- On Connection Strings, add a new one or edit the existing one, pasting the content that you just copied from the DB (don't forget to input your username and password)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a DB using a trial (there are no restrictions to trial account as far as I'm aware of, well, except money). I'm not sure how to workaround this issue, as the template is pre-built by VS.

The more I look at this error, the more I don't get it. There is no "Free" tier of the Azure SQL DB. And the cheapest (basic) supports up to 2GB database, so this doesn't really restrict you.

Try setting appservice plan to shared? if that doesn't help try deleting everything and just let VS create all the resources for you, it should work in that case.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I looked at the shared-alternative but got the following: "Unauthorized: You tried creating a site in the 'Shared' SKU but your DreamSpark subscription can only create sites in the 'Free' SKU. You can upgrade your subscription to a pay-as-you-go subscription to create sites in any sku.  You can still create free sites with the upgraded subscription"

Now think I might go on and try the "delete everything" option.

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with DreamSpark, looks like it really has some limitations... because trial doesn't (except 30 days and money). I don't know if VS can handle that type of subscription. might be not, get back to me with your findings, please. @MrJalapeno

Comment: Thought I'd get back to you, even though I'm still not sure exactly what went wrong and why. So I went over to a friend the day after and we worked at it for some time. In the end we tried to publish it without a specified database added which worked, no errors. And, as it turns out, this led to it connecting to the database I had created on Azure without issues.